# XSS Protection from Query Strings in Java

Tags: java, url, escaping

Looking for input on the code below. Generally, the idea is to take a String representing a URL query string such as `param1=blah&param2=blah` and encode them to protect against possible XSS attack. Using existing utilities (i.e. `UrlEncodedUtils`) is not an option.

```
public static Map<String, List<String>> getParamsFromQueryString(String queryString) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    Map<String, List<String>> params = new HashMap<>();


    for (String param : queryString.split("&")) {
        String[] pair = param.split("=");
        String key = ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML(URLDecoder.decode(pair[0], "UTF-8"));
        String value = "";
        if (pair.length > 1) {
            value = ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML(URLDecoder.decode(pair[1], "UTF-8"));
        }

        // skip ?& and &&
        if ("".equals(key) && pair.length == 1) {
            continue;
        }

        List<String> values = params.get(key);
        if (values == null) {
            values = new ArrayList<>();
            params.put(key, values);
        }
        values.add(value);
    }

    return params;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to RotoRa's answer:

Instead of

```
    String[] pair = param.split("=");
```

you should call

```
    String[] pair = param.split("=", 2);
```

Otherwise you will trim base64-encoded data, which may happen in some applications, especially if the client forgets to properly encode the `=` characters.

Instead of a `HashMap`, use a `LinkedHashMap`, since that will keep the parameters in the same order as they appeared in the original URL. This makes the code easier to test (you do have unit tests, I hope) and more predictable in general.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure about the point of this function. What use is a map of parsed *and* HTML-encoded query parameters? Normally I'd expect to parse the parameters, do something with them and then - if I want to display them directly in an HTML page, which in itself is relatively rare - let the template engine encode them along with everything else I'm outputting.

---

Generally a function/method should only do one thing. Here you are parsing the parameters and encoding them in one. Personally I'd use an existing URL parser library and then do the encoding afterwards.

---

In Java 8 `Map` has a `computeIfAbsent` method, that makes add a new list to the map much easier:

```
params.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new ArrayList()).add(value);
```

Comment: This is a legacy application, and I'm limited to Java 7 syntax. There is also no template engine, only servlets and (ugly) JSPs. In this case I need to safely build a query string (safe meaning protected from potential XSS attack).

Comment: I still don't get it. You need to safely **build** a query string, why are you escaping while **parsing** one? Also why just encode the query parameters? Just encode the complete final URL, since the `&`s in the URL need to be encoded anyway.

Comment: Moreover, the three of most dangers characters in XSS are `<`, `>` and `"`, which are not allowed in URLs anyway, so they should be URL-encoded when building the URL. Actually other than `&` and `'` there are no problematic characters allowed in URLs , and you are not even encoding `&`.